# How to do an inset plot in bokeh?

Tags: bokeh

I couldn't find a single example of inset plots with bokeh. I'm looking to do something similar to the following: http://akuederle.com/matplotlib-zoomed-up-inset

Where I could have an inset that shows a zoomed in version of the main plot. How can one do this with bokeh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Bokeh 1.3.4, this is still an [open feature request](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3821).